# Connection Refused While Connecting to Upstream Client?

Tags: nginx, connection

I am seeing this error in my nginx log.

```
[error] 4383#0: *10160 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client:
```

Anyone have any idea what this means and how to fix it?

G-Man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops!  Seems httpd wasn't starting on boot.

Comment: Can you clarify?